# Div Stacking using Z-Index

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-position

So I'm having trouble with my footer and div stacking.

This looks fine in Google Chrome but in firefox the newsletter image is still dropping all my text down. I can easily using a `position: relative; top: -43px` but then I get a 43px space @ the bottom of the page which also sucks. I've been playing around with z-index and position absolute vs relative all day not sure why it keep dropping down in FF only. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Under the gray bar there's white on white text which should be in the gray bar next to the small logo.

Comment: Looks just fine here, in FF5.

Comment: @bobek Hmm I've viewed it on a couple different versions and resolutions it shows the same error. There's white on white txt under the gray bar which needs to be IN the gray bar right next to the small logo

Comment: try changing margin-top to just top:-47px;

Comment: @bobek if I put `top: -47px` then I get a 47 pixel space between the gray bar and the end of my HTML page which is also no good :/
I'm trying to get my HTML page to end right @ the gray bar, otherwise it will be unused space below it ya konw?

Comment: [Here's how it looks on different browsers](http://browsershots.org/http://trileafdesigns.com/).

Comment: try my answer. You get a small logo and the text on the right

Comment: @Radu do people really still use the netscape browser?!?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, way too few to matter. But hey, it renders even on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
#copyright img
{
    float:left;
}

#copyright p
{

    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: right but there's still a z-indexing problem since the "newsletter" image is keeping it from floating entirely left. Thanks!

Comment: add position:absolute to one of them. You can specify z-index with positioning an element to either absolute or relative

Comment: no luck, relative does nothing and absolute puts it too far left. Then resolution problems kick in with position absolute :/

Comment: can you draw in paint what would you like to see where?

Comment: I have it looking find in firefox now but the style differences have killed me cross browser. In Chrome it is now negative margin'd behind the newsletter bar

Comment: have a look here http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftrileafdesigns.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: >there is no attribute "target" in anchor tag --
I dislike validators xD  thanks for your help but I think im just going to hide the footer on chrome for the time being

Answer (score 1):

Try changing margin-top to -14px:

```
#copyright p {
    margin-top: -14px;
}
```

This displays like this (Firefox 7.0.1):

[image: Fix]

Comment: I see what your getting at sorta worked. Now I just need to get that tiny logo aligned left of it. Lemme play around with that Thanks

Comment: @bobek actually seems to have fixed it (by the way, won't that logo actually end up on the top of the newspaper thing?)

Comment: I got this to work in firefox +1 but now it looks funny in chrome :/